# Magento 2 - Configurable Options Selected Not Showing In Minicart

Tags: magento2, minicart

We have recently noticed that the selected options on a configurable product aren't showing in the minicart. It will show the Labels for the options on the product, but not the selected options.

Answer (score 1):

we had the same problem with a custom attribute. I solved it changing the backend type from varchar to int in eav_attribute table:

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET backend_type='int' WHERE attribute_id=YOUR_ATTIRUBUTE_ID;
```